# Galleriffic plugin extra spaces

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, galleriffic

I'm using the jquery Galleriffic plugin, here is part of the code that is generated by the script :

```
    <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
<span class="image-wrapper current" style="opacity: 1; ">
<a class="advance-link" rel="history" href="#2" title="Title #0">
&nbsp;<img alt="Title #0" src="images/products/Classic.jpg"></a></span></div>
```

This space before the img tag is causing the image to display in the wrong place, I dont know why the script generates such space, but I thought I should remove the space instead.

I tried the following code, but it didnt work.

```
$('a.advance-link').text( $('a.advance-link').text().replace(/\s+/g, "") );
```

I also tried this one

```
$('a.advance-link:contains("&nbsp;")').html(function(i, h) {
                        return h.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                      });
```

but no luck, can somebody figure out how would i remove it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a look at the plugin.

```
// Construct new hidden span for the image
var newSlide = this.$imageContainer
.append('<span class="image-wrapper current"><a class="advance-link" rel="history" href="#'+this.data[nextIndex].hash+'" title="'+imageData.title+'">&nbsp;</a></span>')
.find('span.current').css('opacity', '0');

newSlide.find('a')
    .append(imageData.image)
    .click(function(e) {
        gallery.clickHandler(e, this);
});
```

You'll notice that it first constructs the string you're talking about, then it appends the imageData into the anchor. The result is that the `&nbsp;` tag is never replaced. You could try simply changing that `.append(imageData.image)` to `.html(imageData.image)` and seeing if that doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: This is very smart way to handle it, but unfortunately it didnt work, I even tried to remove the &nbsp; but it still showed up in the code

Comment: @Digital fortress That's very odd. Could you put up a jsFiddle by chance?

Comment: I think fixing the plugin takes so much time, isnt easier to fix the bug in the code by removing the extra space ?